# Starting a template with </pre> tag in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am confused as to why would one want to start the a template for dataview.List with a  tag. Is it because it is expected that Sencha architecture would have a

```
 tag before it, and we want to compensate for that?
```

`Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesList", {
    extend: "Ext.dataview.List",
    alias: "widget.noteslist",
    config: {
        loadingText: "Loading Notes...",
        emptyText: '</pre>
<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No notes found.</div>
<pre>',
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        itemTpl: '</pre>
<div class="list-item-title">{title}</div>
<div class="list-item-narrative">{narrative}</div>
<pre>',
    }
});`

Comment: Where did you get this code from? An example? It seems outright wrong and I've never used anything like above.

Comment: @Saki I got it from this tutorial : http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-2/

Comment: Well, whatever problem is author trying to solve with the above code, it is not a good practice. Normally, you have [`itemTpl`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-cfg-itemTpl) as a div into which you render the item. Don't use such ugly coding practices, please.